# Change "view-order/order-id" url/endpoint in WooCommerce My account - orders to "orders/order-id"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, orders

Currently the URL, under the WooCommerce 'My orders' tab, for the button when you view an order in detail is equal to ***/my-account/view-order/ORDER-ID/***

I would like to change this url to ***/my-account/orders/ORDER-ID/*** - So:

- current url: */my-account/view-order/ORDER-ID/*
- new url: */my-account/orders/ORDER-ID/*

---

Therefore, via the WooCommerce settings I changed the ***view-order*** endpoint to ***orders***

This works, the url of the button to view the order in detail has effectively been changed, only I get the following message on the order detail page

> 'No order has been made yet'.

I believe through the following code, which can be found in */plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php* | line 1675

```php
/**
 * Generates a URL to view an order from the my account page.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function get_view_order_url() {
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_view_order_url', wc_get_endpoint_url( 'view-order', $this->get_id(), wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ), $this );
}
```

I can achieve my goal, but I could use some advice. Anyone who can guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the ***/my-account/view-order/ORDER-ID/*** url to ***/my-account/orders/ORDER-ID/*** can be done by applying a few steps.

---

**Step 1)** change the view order endpoint

The URL for each endpoint can be customized in WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced in the page setup section

[image: account endpoints]

**OR** you use the `woocommerce_get_endpoint_url` filter hook instead

```php
function filter_woocommerce_get_endpoint_url( $url, $endpoint, $value, $permalink ) {
    // Specific endpoint
    if ( $endpoint === 'view-order' ) {
        // New URL
        $url = $permalink . 'orders/' . $value;
    }

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_endpoint_url', 'filter_woocommerce_get_endpoint_url', 10, 4 );
```

While the endpoint is now changed, you will see the following message when viewing the new url:

> 'No order has been made yet'.

This is because the */myaccount/orders.php* template file is loaded, while this should be the */myaccount/view-order.php* template

---

**Step 2)** provide that the correct template file is loaded, this for both the ***/my-account/orders/*** and ***/my-account/orders/ORDER-ID/*** url.

Therefore we need to overwrite the existing `woocommerce_account_orders()` function, which can be found in the */includes/wc-template-functions.php* file. So that our custom function is executed

```php
function woocommerce_account_orders( $current_page ) {
    global $wp;

    // For view-order template file
    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['orders'] ) && is_numeric( $wp->query_vars['orders'] ) ) {
        $order_id = $wp->query_vars['orders'];

        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        if ( ! $order || ! current_user_can( 'view_order', $order_id ) ) {
            echo '<div class="woocommerce-error">' . esc_html__( 'Invalid order.', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) . '" class="wc-forward">' . esc_html__( 'My account', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a></div>';

            return;
        }

        // Backwards compatibility.
        $status       = new stdClass();
        $status->name = wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() );

        wc_get_template(
            'myaccount/view-order.php',
            array(
                'status'   => $status, // @deprecated 2.2.
                'order'    => $order,
                'order_id' => $order->get_id(),
            )
        );
    } else {
        $current_page    = empty( $current_page ) ? 1 : absint( $current_page );
        $customer_orders = wc_get_orders(
            apply_filters(
                'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query',
                array(
                    'customer' => get_current_user_id(),
                    'page'     => $current_page,
                    'paginate' => true,
                )
            )
        );

        wc_get_template(
            'myaccount/orders.php',
            array(
                'current_page'    => absint( $current_page ),
                'customer_orders' => $customer_orders,
                'has_orders'      => 0 < $customer_orders->total,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

**Important:** it is not the intention to change this function by changing the core file!! you can simply add this to *functions.php*, this is because this function is embedded by `if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_account_orders' ) ) {`

---

**Step 3)** this step is optional. This ensures that the ***/my-account/view-order/ORDER-ID/*** url (which is now the old url) is no longer reachable

```php
function action_woocommerce_account_view_order_endpoint() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_account_view-order_endpoint', 'woocommerce_account_view_order' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_view-order_endpoint', 'action_woocommerce_account_view_order_endpoint', 1 );
```

---

**Code from step 1, 2 and 3** goes in *functions.php* file of the active child theme (or active theme).

---

Related: [Change title custom "view-order" endpoint in WooCommerce My account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72389247/11987538)