# Change title custom "view-order" endpoint in WooCommerce My account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, orders

I have added the title to all the pages of the account using the following code:

```php
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wc_page_endpoint_title' );
the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );
```

Path: *plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-account.php*

```
<?php
/**
 * My Account page
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/my-account.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.5.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

/**
 * My Account navigation.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_account_navigation' ); ?>

<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">
    <?php
        add_filter( 'the_title', 'wc_page_endpoint_title' );
        the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );
    ?>
    <?php
        /**
         * My Account content.
         *
         * @since 2.6.0
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_account_content' );
    ?>
</div>
```

I also changed the url of the view-order page using the following url :

[Change "view-order/order-id" url/endpoint in WooCommerce My account - orders to "orders/order-id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72239000/change-view-order-order-id-url-endpoint-in-woocommerce-my-account-orders-to)

- Title **Before** the change url view-order page : order # (order-id)
- Title **after** the change url view-order page : orders

I want it to be the same as **before**

The following code does not work either:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_endpoint_view_order_title( $title, $endpoint, $action ) {
   $title = __( 'test', 'woocommerce' );
   return $title;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_endpoint_view-order_title', 'filter_woocommerce_endpoint_view_order_title', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the changes you made, you also changed the endpoint. To make this run smoothly for that specific change, you must:

Replace:

```php
<?php
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'wc_page_endpoint_title' );
    the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );
?>
```

With:

```php
<?php
    function filter_the_title( $title, $id ) {
        global $wp;

        if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['orders'] ) && is_numeric( $wp->query_vars['orders'] ) ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $wp->query_vars['orders'] );
            /* translators: %s: order number */
            $title = ( $order ) ? sprintf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_order_number() ) : '';
        } else {
            $title = wc_page_endpoint_title( $title );
        }

        return $title;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'filter_the_title', 10, 2 );
    the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );
?>
```

---

Related: [Change "view-order/order-id" url/endpoint in WooCommerce My account - orders to "orders/order-id"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72246941/11987538)