# causing problems in orders pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i asked this question before and got an answer : [Change "view-order/order-id" url/endpoint in WooCommerce My account - orders to "orders/order-id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72239000/change-view-order-order-id-url-endpoint-in-woocommerce-my-account-orders-to)

first of all, i would like to thank the user **7uc1f3r** for answering my question

now, when i check, if I want to go to other pages of the orders, i encounter the **Invalid order**.

- /my-account/orders/ => it brings the list of orders without any problem
- /my-account/orders/2/ => it does not bring the list of orders and gives **Invalid order**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is possible to change the "view-order" endpoint to be same as the "orders" endpoint, it is something that you should not do.

What you actually did is change the `/my-account/orders/[PAGE-NAMBER]` to behave as `/my-account/orders/[ORDER-ID]`. now when you are trying to rich the second orders page WC thinks that you're trying to get order with id 2 instead.

You need to change the single endpoint to `order` (or something different than orders) to make it work. or change the endpoint of the orders page instead, but they can’t work properly when they are sharing the same endpoint.